# Python- remove sparsity from training data for training

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to train a data using neural network using tensorflow. The problem is in my training data---- X_train.When i wrote this on terminal-

```
>>> X_train

>>>*<5979149x1232279 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 24528898 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>*
```

Due to which there is an error which is occurring while training neural network.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "second.py", line 17, in <module>
    x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, len(X_train[0])])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 199, in __len__

>>>    raise TypeError("sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz()"
emphasized text 
***TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]***
```

Can anyone please help me out with this!!!!

Comment: Do you have `5979149 * 1232279 * 2 / 1024**3` - 13TiB or `5979149 * 1232279 * 4 / 1024**3` - 27TiB of RAM?

Comment: @Chirag no-one is going to answer this question. You need to explain with full context what the problem is, and what possible solutions you have tried. Also try to format your text correctly, using the code formatting option for code, etc.

Comment: Add a tensorflow tag.   Read tensorflow doc on how to use a sparse matrix.  This one is too large to convert to dense.